# Endless Scroller Enemy Spawning cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing an Endless Scroller type of game and I need help with ways to spawn enemies. I have two background images that repeat over and over. I spawn the enemy just above the screen then schedule an update to move the position down.

The current way I'm spawning the enemies at the start is just scheduling a selector every 8 seconds, then based on the score, I unschedule the selector and reschedule it again for 6 seconds etc. My character doesnt shoot you just have to navigate around the enemies so the quickest I can have the selector scheduled is 3 seconds otherwise there isnt enough of a gap to get around them.

I'm only new to programming and cocos2d so I'm not to sure how expensive the unschedule and schedule will be.

So basically my question is, Is there a better way of spawning the enemies? keeping in mind that there always has to be a path to survive?

Comment: sounds fine to me. when in doubt, test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are to either use the ccScheduler, or implement your own via a timer in update(). Something along the lines of `if nextWaveTime > timeBetweenWaves`. I would recommend using the scheduler in Cocos2D because I'm sure it has some optimizations built in by some very smart people. Also, scheduling is 'a drop in the bucket' compared to the cost of draw calls. Be sure to reuse the enemies if at all possible. When active enemies go off the screen, don't remove them but instead place them back at the desired 'enter screen' point.